# Where can I find webcam drivers for a cs3006nv HP Pavilion 15 laptop? I have Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: drivers, hp, webcam

This is what my sudo /bin/lsusb command gives me back!

[sudo /bin/lsusb - cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTS6M.png)

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:03bc Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP Wide Vision HD Camera

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b00a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: Text belongs in the question not as a picture. I would be checking with the camera mfg to see if their product is even going to work with Ubuntu.

Comment: That is not how Linux works, We use a generic driver and use a device.  Add your user to the group of the device (probably /dev/video0 or video1)